# Ant with IntelliJ IDEA encoding problems

Tags: java, intellij-idea, encoding, utf-8, ant

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA with Ant on Windows 10 to compile & run my project using build.xml

- All my files (even build.xml) are coded in UTF-8

[image: Files are UTF]

- I'm using UTF-8 in XML specification & javac command

  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?`>
  `<javac target="1.8" srcdir="${test}" destdir="${build}" encoding="UTF-8" includeantruntime="false"`>
- I have set UTF-8 as default encoding in IDE

[image: Default encoding in IDE]

Still not working. It writes diamonds with question marks when there are some diacritics on output.

May it be something related to that I'm making JAR file which is then executed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is to add jvm argument within `build.xml` file.

Example:

```
<target name="execute" description="Launch an app" depends="jar">
    <java jar="${dist}/${jarname}" dir="${dist}" fork="true">
        <jvmarg value="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"/>
    </java>
</target>
```